# Handling UIImage event animation?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'd like to animate an `UIImage` or an `UIImageView much like the`UILabel`text attribute is being manipulated here when a button is pressed. I'm not entirely sure what class to set in`.h`or what class to initialize in`.m`

```
//demo
.h
IBOutlet UILabel* timerLabel;
.m
-(IBAction) didTap {
timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" hi"];
}

//must fix
.h
IBOutlet UIImage* hi;
//or??
IBOutlet UIImageView* hi;

.m
-(IBAction) didTap {
hi.attribute = [UIImage imageNamed: image2];???
}
```

Can someone help me set this up including allocating all necessary image data. i.e. writing a line of code that would alter a storyboard "IBOutlet" image.

*update I set:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *yourImageView;
```

In `.h` and set:

```
yourImageView.image = newimage;
```

In `.m` I also tried:

```
yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:newimage.png];
```

But am still getting a warning?

Comment: `yourImageView.image = newImage;`

Comment: do you have any other variations of this code?

Comment: You can set image like that:

 
`yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newimage.png"];`

Comment: Hi your problem solved or not.... what is actual your problem

Answer (score 0):

To create the IBOutlet for your imageView you would want to use:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView* hi;
```

Once you have created that, make sure to link it to your image view in Interface Builder.

Then, assuming you have a file called "image2.png" in you project, you could use the code:

```
self.hi.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"newblue.png"];
[outlet1 setImage:image];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for full code changing the image at button click

---

**xib approach is**

---

drag and drop an imageView obj from toolbar

1. set the image for imageView in identity inspector (make sure you have that image in current project folder)
2. create the outlet for imageView in .h of your view controller class 
   would look like
3. @property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView ;
4. write @ synthesize myImageView in .m of view controller

put a button on xib/storyboard in the same fashion
create an IBAction for this
under IBAction method write this

```
myImageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImageName"];
```

**if ur  not using xib**

write under viewDidLoad

```
UIimageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initwithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)]]; // any Cordinates 
MyImageView.Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImageName"];
```

set the image as for xib solution we did
Hope this will help you out .